# use highchart and highstock on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highstock1.1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts2.1.4.js"></script>
```

and in the page I use

```
$.getJSON(
        "server/indice.server.php?row=" + row +"&item="+ item,
        null,
        function(data)
        {
            chartindice = new Highcharts.Chart(
            {
                chart:
                {
                    renderTo: 'graph',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                        /////moore setting..
                series:
                [{
                    type: 'area',
                    name: titleindice,
                    data: indice,
                    showInLegend : false //disable the the show/hide icon
                }]


            });
        });
```

and an highstock graph

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartHistory'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2
    },


    series: [{
        data: history,
        type: 'spline',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

and they can't work together, just one or the other.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to display them separarated ? What happened ?

Comment: yes, even seperatly the highchart graph is not working (well).. Is there a highstock+highchrt js file anywhere?

Comment: Can you log your series' data and post here ?

Answer (score 36):

Got same trouble with conflicting Highchart and Highstock. here's the official solution:

> Keep in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of
>   Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and
>   StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js
>   file.

http://highcharts.com/errors/16

Comment: What will be the expiry date if i download highchart.js after registering for non-comercial purpose. ?

Answer (score 5):

Highcharts is included in highstock.js, so please take look at the example, how use highcharts with `highstock.js`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/PtXhB/

Secondly I advice to use the newest highstock.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same problem when I tried to use Highstock chart and Angular Gauge,
And the problem was solved when I try to rearrange highstock highchart javascript library like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

or (if you don't want to use additional graphics)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/Highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
```

I hope it can be useful

Answer (score 2):

you must delete this file:

highcharts.js

i tried and it works

Answer (score 1):

Im my case, including only HighStock's file worked for HighChart's as well.

I have many charts, highchart's or highstock's, possible to be included on same page, and I just call HighStock.js once and it works for both !

Answer (score 1):

Use just 
**highstock.js** 
and delete **highcharts.js** 
And It's work well for me 
And Good luck

Comment: What will be the expiry date if i download highchart.js after registering for non-comercial purpose. ?

Answer (score 0):

Highstock contains most of HighCharts code. Have you tried including only highstock.js in your page to display both charts ?

Comment: I did, it draws only some the highchart graphs but doesn't work in most of them.

Comment: for example the first chart in the question is not showing - (new Highcharts.Chart)

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and got fixed by ordering my JS as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/highcharts.js"></script>
```

I don't know its working fine according Ardi. Is works fine for me when i load highstock.js first followed by highcharts.