# using Highstock and Highchart-Gantt on same page

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I am trying to use the [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) set of javascript libraries to create a page that displays both a stock prices chart and a gantt chart (using the [Highstocks](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/products/highstock/) and [Highcharts Gantt](https://www.highcharts.com/products/gantt/) libraries)

I do not have problems creating and displaying either of these plots independently on separate pages.

However, I cannot get the two libraries to work together in order to display these two plots on the same webpage.

I would appreciate any help i can get on how to get these two libraries to work together.

### Attempt 1. If I import the highstock script first

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>
```

then the following happens:

- the prices plot will display but the gantt plot does not.
- It throws two error messages in the console:

  ```
  Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
  at m (highstock.src.js:463)
  at Object.d.error (highstock.src.js:474)
  at highcharts-gantt.src.js:21
  at highcharts-gantt.src.js:9
  ```

  and

  ```
  Uncaught TypeError: Highcharts.ganttChart is not a function
      at myExample.html:60
  ```

### Attempt 2. If I import the gantt script first

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

then the following happens:

- the gantt plot will display but the prices plot does not.
- It throws two error messages in the console:

  ````
  Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
      at d (highcharts-gantt.src.js:463)
      at Object.c.error (highcharts-gantt.src.js:474)
      at highstock.src.js:21
      at highstock.src.js:9    ```

  and
  ````

  Uncaught TypeError: Highcharts.stockChart is not a function
  at myExample.html:28

### Example Code

A minimum viable code for demonstrating the problem i am running into is below:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- PRICES PLOT -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <div id="pricesChart" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var prices =
            [[Date.parse("2019-06-01 00:00:00"), 0.081558],
             [Date.parse("2019-06-02 00:00:00"), 0.081728],
             [Date.parse("2019-06-03 00:00:00"), 0.081624],
             [Date.parse("2019-06-04 00:00:00"), 0.08164500000000001]
             ];

        var lineplotOptions = {
            xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
            series: [{
                    type: "line",
                    data: prices,
                    yAxis: 0,
                }],
        };

        Highcharts.stockChart('pricesChart', lineplotOptions);
    </script>

    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- GANT CHART -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tasks =
            [{
                start: Date.parse("2019-06-01 06:00:00"),
                end: Date.parse("2019-06-01 20:30:00"),
                name: 'task1'
            }, {
                start: Date.parse("2019-06-01 09:20:00"),
                end: Date.parse("2019-06-03 02:00:00"),
                name: 'task2'
            }, {
                start: Date.parse("2019-06-02 11:00:00"),
                end: Date.parse("2019-06-03 21:10:00"),
                name: 'task1'
            }];

        var gant_options = {
            yAxis: { uniqueNames: true },
            scrollbar: {enabled: true },
            series: [{
                name: 'Project 1',
                data: tasks
            }]
        }

        var mychart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container', gant_options);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Similar questions on stackoverflow

The following are similar questions on stack overflow, but which don't quite deal with my specific case.

- [Using highcharts & highstock together on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517950/using-highcharts-highstock-together-on-same-page)
- [use highchart and highstock on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324790/use-highchart-and-highstock-on-the-same-page)

  - These two deal with `highcharts` and `highstock` libraries on the same page.
  - `Highstock` library extends on the functionality of highcharts, so there is no need to also import highcharts.
  - This does not help my case because the functionality i need is not included in either `highstock` or `highcharts-gantt` on their own.

Comment: created a sandbox with above example https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-fermat-77q2t?fontsize=14 and its working fine for me.

Comment: @VishalRajole , But it is not showing the Gantt chart. Only the prices plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load `highstock` and `highcharts-gantt` separately like that:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script>
    var Highstock = window.Highcharts;
    window.Highcharts = null;
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>
```

initialization:

```
Highstock.stockChart('container1', {
  series: [{
    data: []
  }]
});

Highcharts.ganttChart('container2', {
  series: [{
    data: []
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lxnjwsb9/1/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Wojciech  :)